# Build a-entity hierachy according to glTF model hierarchy builder

Tags: aframe

I'm testing some glTF parser modifications in order to build an a-entity hierarchy according to the 3D objects hierarchy of the glTF scene.

It works well but then I can't change the position/orientation/scale of the a-entity childrens, from the A-Frame inspector widgets. Only the a-entity root can be moved.

Would you know what is missing?

```
GLTFParser.prototype.loadScenes = function () {

    var json = this.json;
    var extensions = this.extensions;


    // scene node hierachy builder
    // Geff
    function buildNodeHierachy( nodeId, parentObject, allNodes ) {

        var _node = allNodes[ nodeId ];
        parentObject.add( _node );

        if ( _node.type == 'Object3D' && _node != undefined) {
            var entityChild = AFRAME.INSPECTOR.createNewEntity({element: 'a-entity', components: {}});  

            entityChild.setAttribute('visible', _node.visible);
            entityChild.setAttribute('position', _node.position);
            entityChild.setAttribute('rotation', _node.rotation);
            entityChild.setAttribute('scale', _node.scale);

            if(parentObject.type == 'Scene')parentObject.sceneRoot = _node;
            entityChild.setObject3D('mesh', _node);
            entityChild.id = _node.name;

            //}

            if(parentObject.el != undefined){
                parentObject.el.insertBefore(entityChild, null);
                parentObject.el.emit('child-attached', entityChild);
            }
            _node.parent = parentObject;
            entityChild.emit('object3dset', {object: _node, type: 'mesh'}); 
            entityChild.emit('model-loaded', {format: 'gltf', model: _node});   
        }


        var node = json.nodes[ nodeId ];

        if ( node.children ) {

            var children = node.children;

            for ( var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                var child = children[ i ];
                buildNodeHierachy( child, _node, allNodes );

            }

        }

    }

    return this._withDependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

The Inspector should not be involved at all in the code. To create an entity:

```
document.createElement('a-entity');
```

https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#creating-an-entity-with-createelement

Comment: THanks, it's much faster to load a model when using document.createElement instead of AFRAME.INSPECTOR.createNewEntity.

Comment: Then to make translation/roation work on children, I had to remove the line : "_node.parent = parentObject;"